# Scripting Excel with Applescript: Problems with reading a range

Tags: excel, macos, applescript, excel-2011

I have a script that I use to export expense entries from Excel to QIF format.
To create the output files, I have a table in Excel that lists the expense (account) types:

```
PaymentType Category           Acct Type
----------- -----------------  ---------
A           American Express   CCard
B           Bob                Cash
C           Capital One        CCard
E           Expense Income     Bank
N           PNC                Bank
P           PayPal             CCard
S           Sears              CCard
U           USAir MC           CCard
```

The content of the table is labeled: **PaymentSourceTable**

And I have this script to read the contents of the table and subsequently create an output file for each:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    #
    # Get the list of payment sources from the spreadsheet and
    #   create a QIF file for each
    #
    #   Also create the list of filenames corresponding to the sources.
    #   That list will be used when appending expense records to the files.
    #
    set PaymentSources to {}
    tell worksheet ListsWorksheet
        set PaymentSources to value of range PaymentSourceTable
    end tell
```

Everything works very well in the rest of my script but sometimes **PaymentSources** contains the actual table values twice - as if I had appended my table values twice.  The entries appear A-U then A-U again.

It only happens when I run the script from the script menu while in Excel, and then only sometimes.  It never happens if I run the script from the Applescript editor - or at least hasn't happened yet in my many tests. That in itself seems really odd and I keep trying it over and over, thinking I'm just imagining it. :-)

I'm baffled.
Has anyone else seen this or could suggest a way to debug?

btw, I'm using Excel for Mac 2011.

**Update**
As it turns out, PaymentSources was not the problem. the following code was the real culprit:

```
repeat with source in PaymentSources
    set _ptype to item 1 of source
    if _ptype is not equal to "" then
        set _type to "!Type:" & item 3 of source
        set _furl to my constructFileName(source)
        my createFile(_type, _furl)
        set end of FileNames to {item 1 of source, _furl, 0}
    end if
end repeat
```

that and the fact that I defined **FileNames** as a *property*:

```
property FileNames : {}
```

.

I totally missed the fact that properties persist between runs.  Lesson learned.

Comment: Have you tried the script without this line: `set PaymentSources to {}`

Comment: @CraigSmith, Thanks. I tried that and it worked correctly the first time through then reverted back to its bad behavior.

Comment: That's crazy.  Is this your entire code?

Comment: Craig, no there's quite a bit more to it. But as I suspected, it was user error.  A rookie mistake actually.  Turns out it wasn't **PaymentSources** that was the problem.  It was an array of filenames that I filled based on the PaymentSources.  I had defined it as a property which I didn't realize persisted between runs, so each time through, would get appended with another set of names.  Apparently, running from the editor vs from Excel menu invokes separate instances so I would run from the editor and it would work as expected then go to Excel and run with the extra entries.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.